# IndexOf in arrays of objects in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure on the use of indexOf in arrays of objects

The code which is not working is:

```
if (res.locals.company.companies.indexOf(req.query.companyId) >= 0) return next()
```

The if condition will always return false.

I also tested in console and it is actually wrong:

```
>> var zio = { __v: 1,
  _id: '50bc0238049a1ff10b000001',
  companies: 
   [ { _id: '50bc01938f164ee80b000001', name: 'Test' },
     { _id: '50bc01ac4e860ee90b000001', name: 'zio' } ],
}

>> zio.companies.indexOf("50bc01938f164ee80b000001")
-1
```

whereas it should be true.

Should I use any mysterious underscore utility ?

**UPDATE/Clarification:** my aim is just to check if 50bc01938f164ee80b000001 exists in one of the ids, I don't need to know where it actually is. This is very performance critical!

Nodejs solutions or tips would be amazing!

Comment: This looks like the result of a MongoDB query.  It may be better to do this directly in a `find` query instead of post analyzing it.

Comment: it's something I retrieve from my redis (cached query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not wrong. That *Array* does not contain a *String* like that, but only two *Object references*. Hence, the result is correctly `-1`.

To get the index from the *Object reference* containing the searched *string value*, we could go like

```
var index;
zio.companies.some(function( obj, idx ) {
    if( obj._id === '50bc01938f164ee80b000001' ) {
        index = idx;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log('index is: ', index);
```

---

Based on your ninja edit, if you just want to know whether or not an object ref holding a specific *id* is contained by that array, use it like

```
var check = zio.companies.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj._id === '50bc01938f164ee80b000001';
});

if( check.length ) {
    console.log('yep');
} else {
    console.log('nope');
}
```

---

Second edit: If you are really and only after performance, you probably don't want to have any *function call overhead* in any search. I'd use something like

```
function inObject(arr, search) {
    var len = arr.length;
    while( len-- ) {
        if(arr[len]._id === search)
           return true;
    }
}

if( inObject( zio.companies, 'AAA' ) ) {
}
```

That code outclasses any snippet provided here by a few magnitudes. [See Here](http://jsperf.com/json-stringify-vs-prototype-filter/2)

Comment: For the simple existence test, why not use the boolean returned from `some` instead of using `filter` and a separate `length` check?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: yes that would be absolutely possible also of course. I just felt like doing it with `.filter()` here.

Comment: I was tempted to go this way. Apparently the for loop is faster than filter/lenght and some :/ http://jsperf.com/json-stringify-vs-prototype-filter

Comment: @haskellguy: of course such a loop is faster, but you didn't mention that this operation is very performance critical. Anyway, the `.filter()` should be *that* much slower, but its way more convenient code and shorter to write.

Comment: `filter` will take, on average, twice as long, and switching from `filter` to `some`/`any` would be a trivial change.  Why not make it?

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but a comment about the jperf results of the "Second edit" (just speed comments, not approach). The object array has the search object last, and the code snippet that appears so fast is searching from the end of the array. Of course that would be faster.

Comment: @clay Party is never over. You're right. Anyways, the native looping is still way faster than all functional-loops provided here. See http://jsperf.com/json-stringify-vs-prototype-filter/4

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over the elements and check for the `_id` being equal.

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) checks for strict equality, and those objects are of course not equal to that string.  (It's the same logic as `"hello" === {foo: "hello"}`.  That will always be false.)

I'm sure with node there's some fancy way to do that, but the bare-JS way is:

```
var i,
    arr = [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'baz'}],
    idx = -1;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i].foo === 'bar') {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also easily turn that into a function:

```
function indexOf(arr, pred) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (pred(arr)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That would give you a lot more verbose usage though (and a bit worse performance), but it might also be a bit more flexible if you find yourself needing to do it often.

```
console.log(indexOf(arr, function(elem) { return elem.foo === 'bar'; });
```

Comment: isnt this blocking on node?

Comment: @haskellguy Yes, but an asynchronous indexOf would be silly (and would require much lower level code without some crazy hackery).

Comment: I see, I see. Looks to me quite fast respect to others :) http://jsperf.com/json-stringify-vs-prototype-filter

Answer (score 0):

Your `companies` seems to be an array of objects (not ids), which has `Id` as one of the attributes. `indexOf` function is used to find the index of the matching element. **Since you are passing an ID value to search the index, its not finding it as an element on the array hence returning false.**

To fix the problem, you have two options:

1. Iterate the companies element compare the ID value, if matched return true otherwise false.
2. Use the object with desired id in as argument in the `indexOf` function. If value is greater than -1, return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOf` is returning the correct output; your array doesn't have an element with that string. In fact, it's an array holding two object literals. You don't need `.indexOf` for objects, instead we must make our own function:

```
 var inObject = function( object, val ) {

     for (var i in object) { if ( object.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {

             if ( obj[i] === val ) {

                 return true;
             }

         }

     }
     return false;
 };

>>> inObject( zio.companies[0], '50bc01938f164ee80b000001' );
    : true
```

Comment: isnt this blocking on node?

Comment: @haskellguy No. How is it blocking?